# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" but there is no error

Tags: javascript, chromium, userscripts

I'm authoring a simple userscript that will give the backspace button navigation control like in windows (specifically this is for linux users) for Chromium browser.

This script *was* working, then I made a few alterations to it (very simple stuff, commenting, tabbing, making it pretty), and now i'm getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

on this line

```
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

The script is located [here](https://github.com/rlemon/UserScripts/blob/master/Backtrack/backtrack.user.js) - i'm pulling out my hair trying to figure this out.

The script really only applies to chromium as ff gives you a configuration option to enable this functionality.. 
 - Chromium 15.0.874.106 (Developer Build 107270) Ubuntu 11.10

**Edit** *if someone can tell me why this doesn't work that would be great*

```
EmbedCodeOnPage("(function() {" + fn.toString() + "})();"); // fails
EmbedCodeOnPage("(" + fn.toString() + ")()"); // works.
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the script code that's being injected.

Comment: Firebug gives a different error here: http://jsfiddle.net/RWtTx/, mainly, `function statement requires a name (function() {function () { `.

Comment: Why not store the head like `var headtag =  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]`, and then do `headtag.appendChild(script)`?

Comment: This is a little cargo-cult but I'd also try sticking a semicolon at the front of your "wrapper" (before its open-paren).

Comment: Oh, I was answering before I saw your edit. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are just dropping in an anonymous function and not executing it

change line 46 and add ()

Comment: That's definitely not what they are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the actual error is here:

```
function EmbedFunctionOnPageAndExecute(fn) {
    EmbedCodeOnPage("(function() {" + fn.toString() + "})();");
}
```

`fn.toString` is already going to format your function like this:

```
function () { /* code here */ }
```

So you're going to end up with this:

```
(function() { function () { /* code here */ } })();
```

This is clearly not what you want. You want to execute the inner function.

Comment: +1 for a better explanation in the answer. Thomas however had the same conclusion in the chat room :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, even with simple function. This might be due to incorrect syntax of the function definition itself, especially switching between java to javascript.

if i declare function with in an object definition such as    calculateTax(){//some logic;} and run, i get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" -  this is due to the fact that function declaration is not correct format/syntax. The error is misleading, however by changing it to    calculateTax : function(){//some logic;} resolves the issue. Hope this helps. Thanks.