# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (, no error visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, error-handling

I am writing an AJAX function, but it looks like there is an error. I can't seem to find any. Please help! I have browsed these questions: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733275/chrome-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-illegal), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482681/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-but-there-is-no-error), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231532/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-no-visible-error) but none of it is working. Here is my code:

```
      function registerDevice(fp,uid)
  {
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         async: true,
         url: "backend.php",
         data: {"fp": fp, "uid" : uid},
         success: function(output) {
          var json = eval('(' + output + ')');
          var status = json['status'];
          if(status == "success")
          {
            //redirect user.
            setTimeout(function(){
                    //do what you need here
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_GET['goto'])) 
                      {
                        echo 'window.location.replace("'.$_GET["goto"].'");';
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        echo 'window.location.replace("index.php");';         
                      }
                    ?>
            }, 2000);
          }
          else
          {
            $("#login-msg").text("Something went wrong. Please try again.");
            $("#login-alert").fadeTo(4000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
            $("#login-alert").hide();
            });
          }
         },
         error: function(error) {
          $("#login-msg").text("There was an unknown error.");
          $("#login-alert").fadeTo(4000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
          $("#login-alert").hide();
        });
         }
    });
  }
```

and it is called like this:

```
    $('body').on("click", "#mybtn", function (e) {
registerDevice(result,uid);   
});
```

Here is the error I get in Google Chrome:

```
VM411:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
success @   login_alpha.php:344
j   @   jquery.js:3148
fireWith    @   jquery.js:3260
x   @   jquery.js:9314
b   @   jquery.js:9718
```

P.S: line 344 refers to this line:

```
var json = eval('(' + output + ')');
```

**Edit 1: backend.php**

```
<?php
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$fp = $_POST['fp'];

//my code here.
$response_array['status'] = "success";
$response_array['type'] = "cookie";

?>
```

Comment: try this way `var json = eval(+'(' + output + ')'+);`

Comment: @guradio Nope, the error still persists. This time from the beginning. Last time it showed up only when the function was called! :(

Comment: What is the content of `output`? Can you consume output as json directly?

Comment: @kazenorin Wait, I'll edit the question with a few more details.

Comment: you didnt parse the output try parsing it first you are returning a json

Comment: Yes, I looked into that thanks to @kazenorin and you. I had the json_encode line commented and that's why the output wasn't in the json format! Well, silly error there! Thanks a lot of quick help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution, and it was very silly.**

The backend.php was **NOT** giving a JSON response!
This was the original code:

```
<?php
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$fp = $_POST['fp'];

//my code here.
$response_array['status'] = "success";
$response_array['type'] = "cookie";

?>
```

I just added this line:

```
echo json_encode($response_array);
```

This made sure I was sending back a JSON response to the AJAX call's success function! What a stupid error.

Final edit for backend.php:

```
<?php
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$fp = $_POST['fp'];

//my code here.
$response_array['status'] = "success";
$response_array['type'] = "cookie";

//print json response
echo json_encode($response_array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval` function needs a string to evaluate. You are trying to eval a JSON Object I think.

Try:

```
var json = eval('(' + JSON.stringify(output) + ')');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: Why bother `eval`-ing it at all then? Since `JSON.stringify` would only stringify valid JSON

Comment: eval would run the script.

Comment: Well, I have already solved the issue. I had the json_encode line commented and that's why the output wasn't in the JSON format! Well, silly error there!